# Python: Concurrent reads and writes to the same file

Tags: python, apache, file

I have an Apache server that writes to a custom log file (through a cgi script) . I also have a Python script that periodically fetches the tail of that log file. Here is my tail function:

```
def tail(f, window = 1):
    f = open(f, 'r')
    BUFSIZ = 1024
    f.seek(0, 2)
    bytes = f.tell()
    size = window
    block = -1
    data = []
    while size > 0 and bytes > 0:
        if (bytes - BUFSIZ > 0):
            # Seek back one whole BUFSIZ
            f.seek(block*BUFSIZ, 2)
            # read BUFFER
            data.append(f.read(BUFSIZ))
        else:
            # file too small, start from begining
            f.seek(0,0)
            # only read what was not read
            data.append(f.read(bytes))
        linesFound = data[-1].count('\n')
        size -= linesFound
        bytes -= BUFSIZ
        block -= 1

    f.close()
    return '\n'.join(''.join(data).splitlines()[-window:])
```

Taken individually, the Python script and the Apache logging both work fine. However, when I have them concurrently work on this same log file, the log file stops being updated.

How can I implement a tail read function in Python that doesn't interfere with Apache writes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can take a look at the [pytailer](http://code.google.com/p/pytailer/) project or this [recipe](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/157035-tail-f-in-python/) on ActiveState for some inspiration on implementation details.

Comment: Implementing a tail function is not the problem/question.

Comment: Except the last line of the question post is "How can I implement a tail read function in Python that doesn't interfere with Apache writes?"

Comment: Yes, and the second part is obviously the key part and not covered in your answer...

Comment: I beg to differ. A proper implementation of `tail -f` won't interfere with Apache logging in the first place, so it is answered.